# Validation on BigDecimals taken as input from Scanner

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner, bigdecimal

I'm taking in user input from the console, which needs to be a BigDecimal. How can I validate this to ensure that it is this type before trying to use it in the program?

Here's how I'm reading it in: `scanner.nextBigDecimal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [hasNextBigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigDecimal--) to validate before reading the value:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
>   interpreted as a BigDecimal using the nextBigDecimal() method.